# How to reducy Poly count just for a specific area?

Tags: 3d-view, sculpting, polycount

Hi I made a mistake while sculpting und now I dont know how to reduce the Poly count on that specific area... I know there ist decimate tool etc.

But that reduces the Poly count for the whole model. Basically do you know how to reduce it only on the lower Part of the Face?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Choose the *Draw* brush, lower its *Strength* down to 0, set the *Detail Size* in the *Dyntopo* panel, sculpt:

[image]